# Xcode application crashing with no errors

Tags: ios, xcode, error-handling

I accidently deleted my Main VC. I brought them back in and reset the target memberships so now I do not receive any errors. The problem is when it launches it now crashes straight away. The project has got so big I dont know where to start to solve the issue. Anyone have any ideas as to where to start with this problem?

Comment: Mark a break point in `main` and step over.

Comment: Are there console messages when you run it?

Comment: wt is error message ??

Comment: No errors when I run it

Comment: enabled NSZombie and nothing happened.Before I had a similar problem when I embedded in a navigational controller but its not that. I just crashes as soon as launched

Comment: Do you mean you deleted the XIB file of your app's root view controller, or you deleted the .h/.m files? Deleting XIB files suck and bringing them back can be a pain depending on linked outlets...just need to know if that's the issue

Comment: Well Jai I am using storyboards so I am not really sure?

Answer (score 0):

I do no you delete .xib or class file but check well your mainviewcontroller.xib is in build phases ->copy bundle resources or if you delete class file mean check is in build phases -> compile sources